# Temperature modelling counter current heat exchanger

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I've written this code to simulate the temperature change along the inner pipe of a bitutular heat exchanger. I used odeint to integrate the coupled differential equations, but I believe something is wrong in the integration part because the energy balance doesn't match '-'

I know it's pretty specific but I thank you for any help, thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'

#anything + tr stands for trietylen glicol
#anything + w stands for water


#trietileno glicol inlet properties
T0 = 363 #K inlet temperature
Wtr = 3.6 #kg/s mass rate

#water inlet properties
t0 = 298 #K inlet temperature
Ww = [0.1, 0.5, 1] #kg/s mass rate

y0 = T0, t0 # Initial condition
Di = 0.07792 #m inner diameter
L = 3.048 #m tube length

U = 283.72 #W/m²K
pi= 3.1415

cptr0 = 1901.09 #J/kgK....
#cpti = (2.7683*T + 896.2) #J/kg*K calor específico
cpw0 = 4018.05 #J/kgK
#cpwi = (-0.00003*(t**3) + 0.0403*(t**2) - 16.277*t + 6083.7)  #J/kg*K calor específico
#Calculus of the derivatives
def funct(y, x, W, cpt, cpw):   
    Ti = y[0]
    ti = y[1]
    dTdx = (Ti - ti)*(U * Di * pi / (Wtr * cpt)) 
    dtdx = (Ti - ti)*(U * Di * pi / (W * cpw)) 
    x = np.linspace(0, L, 100)

    return dTdx, dtdx

#integration
def solve_plot(W, cpw, cpt):

    x = np.linspace(0, L, 300)

    sol = odeint(funct, y0 , x, args = (W, cpw, cpt))

    T = sol[:, 0]
    t = sol[:, 1]

    rev_x = x[::-1]
#plot and printing of the properties in each position of the tube
    print('T1 = {:.2e} K, T2= {:.2e} K\n'
      't1 = {:.2e} K, t2= {:.2e} K\n'.format(T[99],T[0],t[0],t[99]))
    plt.plot(rev_x, T, 'b-', label='Trietileno-glicol', linewidth = 2)
    plt.plot(x, t,'r--', label='Água', linewidth = 2)
    plt.xlabel('Posição(ft)')
    plt.ylabel('Temperatura (F)')
    plt.title('Perfil de temperatura dos fluidos(Ww = {})'.format(W))
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    print('    T        delta_ht        t        delta_hw')
    for i in range(100):
        print('{:.2e} K  {:.2e} W  {:.2e} K  {:.2e} W'.format( T[99-i],(T[99-i] -T[99])*cpt*Wtr, t[i], (t[i]-t[0])*cpw*W))
    print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

    return

solve_plot(W = Ww[0], cpw = cpw0, cpt = cptr0)
solve_plot(W = Ww[1], cpw = cpw0, cpt = cptr0)
solve_plot(W = Ww[2],cpw = cpw0, cpt = cptr0)
```

I expected the outputs column 2 and 4 to be equal, here is part of them:

```
    T        delta_ht        t        delta_hw
3.63e+02 K  0.00e+00 W  2.98e+02 K  0.00e+00 W
3.63e+02 K  -1.52e+01 W  2.98e+02 K  9.71e+01 W
3.63e+02 K  -3.04e+01 W  2.98e+02 K  1.94e+02 W
3.63e+02 K  -4.56e+01 W  2.99e+02 K  2.90e+02 W
3.63e+02 K  -6.10e+01 W  2.99e+02 K  3.86e+02 W
3.63e+02 K  -7.64e+01 W  2.99e+02 K  4.82e+02 W
3.63e+02 K  -9.18e+01 W  2.99e+02 K  5.77e+02 W
3.63e+02 K  -1.07e+02 W  3.00e+02 K  6.72e+02 W
3.63e+02 K  -1.23e+02 W  3.00e+02 K  7.67e+02 W
3.63e+02 K  -1.38e+02 W  3.00e+02 K  8.61e+02 W
3.63e+02 K  -1.54e+02 W  3.00e+02 K  9.55e+02 W
3.63e+02 K  -1.70e+02 W  3.01e+02 K  1.05e+03 W
3.63e+02 K  -1.86e+02 W  3.01e+02 K  1.14e+03 W
```

Comment: specific - good one! :)

Comment: When I run the code example it raises the error `NameError: name 'Wt' is not defined` in line `dTdx = (Ti - ti)*(U * Di * pi / (Wt * cpt))`.

Comment: When I said I expected the columns 2 and 4 to be equal I meant in absolute values.

Comment: Have you compared your code's results against the analytical solution? I'd bet that any major text book on heat transfer will list analytical solution formulas (for temperature distribution and heat transfer rate) for this kind of double-pipe heat exchanger problem.

Comment: I'm gonna do it , thanks